# Function With False returned from Empty Cells

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to make a function that will say True if a cell date has been a year or greater since the current date.

The function I used to get this to work is `=IF(DAYS360(H8,TODAY()) >= 258`, TRUE).

The only problem is if a cell is empty it will also show up as True. To fix this I tried doing this:  `=IF(DAYS360(H7,TODAY()) >= 258,TRUE(AND(H7 = "", FALSE)))`

This didn't really work, but if the date was within the same year it seemed to work. If the function was last year but still less than 365 days it showed up as #N/A (Number of wrong arguments to True, Expected 0 arguments, but got 1)

How can I make the cell show up as True if its been 365 days or more and False if the cell is empty or less than 365 from the cell date. The example cell date in this case shown above would be H7.

All cells shown are using the function `=IF(DAYS360(H7,TODAY()) >= 258,TRUE(AND(H7 = "", FALSE)))`.

Cell with N/A Value with date value from previous year

[image: []

Cell with False value with date value from current year

[image]

Cell with N/A value with empty cell

[image: []

```
 =IF(DAYS360(H8,TODAY()) >= 258, TRUE)
 =IF(DAYS360(H7,TODAY()) >= 258,TRUE(AND(H7 = "", FALSE)))
```

Comment: why 258?  Would it not be 360 for one year?

Comment: Well it's technically not a year, it would just be a heads up before it is actually a year.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=IF(AND(H7<>"",DAYS360(H7,TODAY()) >= 258),TRUE)
```

But that can be shortened to:

```
=AND(H7<>"",DAYS360(H7,TODAY()) >= 258)
```

Which will return the TRUE/FALSE

And really you do not need the `DAYS360` unless you want to force a 30 day month:

```
=AND(H7<>"",TODAY()-H7>258)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That make's a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
=IF(H7="",FALSE,H7<=EDATE(TODAY(),-12))
```

I'd think EDATE([value],-12) would be a better way to get the date a year ago than whatever stuff you're doing with number of days.

Answer (score 1):

> it would just be a heads up before it is actually a year

in that case, you just compare years:

```
=YEAR(A1)>YEAR(TODAY())
```

for arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="",,YEAR(A1:A)>YEAR(TODAY())))
```

[image: 0]